# Angular 7 with adding new component 'the server component' isn't appear in browser when I add a component tag?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

It is first time To use Angular Now I'm learning angular 7:
- I create a new custom component in 
- |src folder
---| app
----|| server (name of my component)

then I added in app.component.html the name of component 
I see in the tutorial show in browser 
the server component
even if he add it empty element
I do all steps in

server.component.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector:'app-server',
    templateUrl: './server.component.html'
})

export class ServerComponent {

}
```

& app.module.ts file

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ServerComponent } from './server/server.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ServerComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: please write you HTML template code here of app.component.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the Angular documentation explains all that.

Comment: I also add it <app-server></app-server> in server.component.html and nothing changed :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you define your `<app-server></app-server>` somewhere?

For instance in the `app.component.html`

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>

    <app-server></app-server>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Also you will find an example here : https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1

Comment: I also add it <app-server></app-server> in server.component.html and nothing changed :(

Answer (score 0):

In your `app.component.html` add :

```
<app-server></app-server>
```

Thus you'll see its HTML.

What you did is in fact kind of **import it and make it visible to other components declared in `AppModule`**, but you didnt call it actually.

Comment: I also add it <app-server></app-server> in server.component.html and nothing changed :(

Comment: in `app.component.html` .. @SarahAhmed